# CMake cannot find source files in a different directory

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to include files from one directory (/source) into test cases in another (/test) but cmake is unable to find any of the files in /source.

The structure of my project:

```
PrettyDD/
    + CMakeLists.txt
    + external/
        + CMakeLists.txt
        + gmock-1.7.0/
    + source/
        + CMakeLists.txt
        + parser.cpp
        + parser.h
        + main.cpp
        + ...
    + test/
        + CMakeLists.txt
        + test1.cpp
```

The error message:

```
marcus@lean-machine:~/Programming/PrettyDD/build$ cmake ../ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles"
-- Could NOT find Threads (missing:  Threads_FOUND) 
-- Could NOT find Threads (missing:  Threads_FOUND) 
-- Configuring done
CMake Error at test/CMakeLists.txt:12 (add_executable):
  Cannot find source file:

    parser.cpp

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp
  .hxx .in .txx
```

`/test/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(GMOCK_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/external/gmock-1.7.0"
    CACHE PATH "The path to the GoogleMock test framework.")

set_property(TARGET gtest APPEND_STRING PROPERTY COMPILE_FLAGS " -w")

include_directories(SYSTEM ${GMOCK_DIR}/gtest/include
                           ${GMOCK_DIR}/include)
include_directories(SYSTEM "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/source")


function(add_gmock_test target)
    add_executable(${target} ${ARGN})
    target_link_libraries(${target} gmock_main)

    add_test(${target} ${target})

    add_custom_command(TARGET ${target}
               POST_BUILD
               COMMAND ${target}
               WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
               COMMENT "Running ${target}" VERBATIM)
endfunction()

add_gmock_test(tests test1.cpp parser.cpp)
```

I have verified that `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/source` points to the right directory by use of CMake's `message()`.

If I explicitly specify the path to `parser.cpp` (`../source/parser.cpp`) in `add_gmock_test()` then it's able to find the file.

I can also successfully run the test if I first build a library out of `parser.cpp` (and it's dependencies) in `/source/CMakeLists.txt` and add it where I link `gmock_main`.

Why can't CMake find `parse.cpp` or any other file in `/source`? What am I doing wrong?

### Edited in after DarthB's answer:

Leaving `parser.cpp` out of `add_gmock_test(tests test1.cpp)` gives me the following error:

```
marcus@lean-machine:~/Programming/PrettyDD/build$ make
[ 55%] Built target PrettyDD
[ 66%] Built target gmock
[ 83%] Built target gmock_main
[ 88%] Built target gtest
[ 94%] Built target gtest_main
Linking CXX executable tests
CMakeFiles/tests.dir/test1.cpp.o: In function `Parser_Construct_Test::TestBody()':
/home/marcus/Programming/PrettyDD/test/test1.cpp:7: undefined reference to `Parser::Parser()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
test/CMakeFiles/tests.dir/build.make:86: recipe for target 'test/tests' failed
make[2]: *** [test/tests] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:316: recipe for target 'test/CMakeFiles/tests.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [test/CMakeFiles/tests.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:86: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

This is what `test1.cpp` looks like:

```
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include "parser.h"

TEST(Parser, Construct) {
  Parser parser;
}
```

`parser.cpp`:s constructor:

```
Parser::Parser() {
    createFunctionMap();
}
```

declared in `parser.h` as:

```
class Parser {
public:
    Parser();
    ...
```

There should be nothing wrong with the constructor as the program itself runs fine. So why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 2):

include_directories() only changes the compiler parameters for include directories, that means you can include "parser.h" somewhere in your test code using

```
#include "parser.h"
```

and .../PrettyDD/source is searched for this file.

I do not think parser.cpp contains test code. So it should not be part of your test project:

```
add_gmock_test(tests test1.cpp)
```

Should be enough. Otherwise you should rethink your project structure.

Alternatively you can also use:

```
add_gmock_test(tests test1.cpp ../source/parser.cpp)
```

EDIT:

Regarding the question in the comments. Nearly every cmake commands' parameter is either relative to ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} or ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}. As far as I know there is no "include_directories" for cmake commands but when listing source files we can also use the [taget_sources()](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/target_sources.html) command.

That means if a CMakeLists.txt is the same folder as the source files it should work to write:

```
target_sources(tests parser.cpp)
```

inside the CMakeLists.txt file of the 'source' folder.

Maybe there are problems because the target is not know yet. I only used [target_sources()](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/target_sources.html) in sub folders of the project containing the source. Whereby I use a structure similar to:

- libs

  - myLib

    - src
    - inc

whereby the src and inc folder also contain a CMakeLists.txt file that explicit lists the source files using [target_sources()](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/target_sources.html) command.

Comment: If I leave `parse.cpp` out of `add_gmock_test` I get a different error. I've updated the question with more info.

Comment: Why dont you use the files in source as a library anymore? You're error messages indicate that there is no source "linked" for the Constructor in Parser (because it is in parser.cpp). That means the test executable does not know about the definition of the Constructor. It only knows its declaration. I use a similar structure in my project but I generate a library for the code and link it against an product executable and against another test executable.

Comment: I use them as libraries now but I want to know why I can't simply add a file with `add_executable` without specifying the full path. It should work so it annoys me.

Comment: As far as i know is every relative path relative either to your ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} or your ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} and this depends on the function and parameter you are using. In case of add_executable() or add_library() the arguments are relative to the source directory. If you want to separate the listings of your targets source from your targets main CMakeLists.txt file you can take a look at target_sources() command. If you use target_sources() in a CMakeLists file that is in the same directory as your source files you should get your desired behavior. I will update my answer